# Laravel pagination & get all

Tags: laravel, api

I have an API endpoint `api/users` that returns Users in paginated form:

```
public function index()
{
    return User::latest()->paginate(10);
}
```

I also need to have access to ALL users as well, however the pagination makes this not possible.

For example I want to get all users as well using:

```
return User::latest()->get();
```

How can I use both without creating another endpoint? e.g. `api/allusers`

Comment: Pass additional parameter to determine all or paginated users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index($page)
{
   if($page=='All')
    {
      return User::latest();
    }
  return User::latest()->paginate($page);
}
```